# Initializing tf.Variable from a Tensor Object (not a tf.Variable)

Tags: variables, initialization, tensorflow

I'm trying to initialize a `tf.Variable` from a tensor object. Normally, from another `tf.Variable` you simply just used the `initialized_value()` but if you make a tensor object this does not work:

```
a = tf.constant([4,5,6])
b = tf.Variable(a.initialized_value())
```

I have tried `b = tf.Variable(a)` but upon `initialize_all_variables()` being ran, tensorflow asks for a placeholder to be filled which is not correct.

The reason why I'm doing this in the first place is that @mrry has suggested to place a tf.Variable into the params argument in `tf.gather` to help speed things up.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
a = tf.constant([4,5,6])
b = tf.Variable(a)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print b.eval()
```

Comment: I ended up just using `tf.assign` after reading your suggestion. I think there was something wrong with how I was initializing the variables. Thanks!